# c3p0 connection pool unable to see physical connections in oracle monitor screen

Tags: connection, connection-pooling, c3p0

```
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class DBconnectionpool{
public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception{
ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass( "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" ); 
cpds.setJdbcUrl( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" );
cpds.setUser("bms");                                  
cpds.setPassword("abc");
cpds.setInitialPoolSize(5);
Connection con = cpds.getConnection();
System.out.println("got the connection"+con);                                  
  }
```

}

after Executing the above code ,In the Oracle monitor page i'm unable to see the 5 physical connections (i.e as i have set  cpds.setInitialPoolSize(5)) instead i see only one connection.

Answer (score 0):

your program exits immediately after one Connection is acquired. try sleeping for 30000 ms after you've acquired your Connection.